# How to rearrange nested arrays?

Tags: javascript

I have an array the contains five nested arrays each with 15 numbers. Is there a way to create a new array which contains 15 nested arrays of 5 numbers, such that the first array contains the first entry from each of the five arrays? So far I have:

```
var allArrCookie = [];
var allArrCookieByHour = [];
function makeCol() {
    for (var i = 0; i < allArrCookie.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < allArrCookie[i].length; j++) {
            allArrCookieByHour.push(allArrCookie);
        }
   }
```

Comment: There is - use a plain old `for` loop. Do it exactly the same way is if you were asked to do that manually on a piece of paper.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to show an example of the input array and the corresponding desired output?

Comment: One issue with code at Question is that `i < allArrCookie.length` is `false` given `var allArrCookie = []`. Is requirement to dynamically create the elements of the arrays?

Comment: @zerkms I was using a for loop, but it doesn't seem simple?

Comment: @guest271314 the array is populated with other code

Comment: Why is "other code" not included at text of Question?  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @guest271314 Because it's a lot of code and it won't all fit with the amount of text I have, nor is it necessary.

Comment: _"Because it's a lot of code and it won't all fit with the amount of text I have, nor is it necessary."_ "a lot" is not a number. Did you try to include the code at Question? Or are you speculating? At a bare minimum perhaps consider taking the time to read the linked help documents.

Comment: @guest271314 I did try to include it all and was told it was too much code, and I have read what you have posted

Comment: @EliSpeigel Why do you not include that use of a `for` loop is required at text of Question, and at least the generated input arrays and expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a fun one. It assumes the array is not empty in either dimension. You could add a check around it for that case.

Given that this looks like a homework assignment, this solution gets the job done but would be thrown out by any teacher.

```
var orig = [
  [101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106],
  [201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206],
  [301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306]
];

var rotated = orig[0].map((_,i) => orig.map(s => s[i]));

/*
output:
[
  [101,201,301],
  [102,202,302],
  [103,203,303],
  [104,204,304],
  [105,205,305],
  [106,206,306]
]
*/
```

Comment: If this exercise is part of a curriculum, it would be part of the introductory "for loops and arrays" section. The answer would require for loops, as that is what a teacher would be testing.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.

Comment: @EliSpeigel Have you read the linked https://stackoverflow.com/help pages?

Comment: @guest271314 I have, while this post was helpful, I'm looking for help with for loops. I'm have a conceptual issue which is not ultimately being addressed.

Comment: @EliSpeigel _"I have, while this post was helpful,"_ How can we verify the same by the contents of your question and comments?  You have not included at least one essential part of the requirement at the text of the Question: _"I'm looking for help with for loops"_